# publish asp net core on TFS build server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tfs

In Visual Studio I have the possibility to "publish" an asp net core app (using .net framework 4.6.1).

[image]

How can I trigger this publish on a tfs build automatically? Do I need a special build task or is it a parameter in "msbuild" step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this through the standard MsBuild task. You need to set a bunch of additional arguments:

```
msbuild mysln.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name>
```

Or you can use the `dotnet publish` from the [dotnet task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core?view=vsts) or a commandline task.